# jsGrid calling Controller .Net Core - Cells not loading data

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, jsgrid

Using `jsGrid` / `.net core 2.2` / `MVC` I'm successfully returning data in my ajax call and logging to the console, but I can't figure out why the fields aren't populated?

My View

```
<div id="jsGrid"></div>

@section scripts {
<script>
    $(function () {

        $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
            height: "50%",
            width: "100%",

            filtering: true,
            inserting: true,
            editing: true,
            sorting: true,
            paging: true,
            autoload: true,

            pageSize: 10,
            pageButtonCount: 5,

            //deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete client?",

            controller: {
                loadData: function () {
                    var d = $.Deferred();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: "/operator/GridJson",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            d.resolve(data);
                            console.log('success ', data);
                        },
                        error: function (e) {
                            alert("error: " + e.responseText);
                        }
                    });

                    return d.promise();
                }                    
            },

            fields: [
                { name: "OperatorId", type: "number", width: 50 },
                { name: "FirstName", type: "text", width: 150 },
                { name: "LastName", type: "text", width: 150 },
                { name: "LicenseNumber", type: "number", width: 50, filtering: false },
                { name: "RFIDNumber", type: "number", width: 50, filtering: false },
                { name: "DateCreated", type: "date", width: 50, filtering: false },
                { name: "LastUpdated", type: "date", width: 50, filtering: false },
                { name: "CompanyId", type: "number", width: 50 }
                //    { type: "control" }
            ]
        });
        console.log("test");

    });
</script>
}
```

My Controller Method

```
[HttpGet]
public string GridJson()
{
    List<OperatorDetail> operators = service.GetOperators();

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(operators);

    return json;

}
```

The Console log

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {OperatorId: 1, FirstName: "driver1", LastName: "driver1", LicenseNumber: 12345, RFIDNumber: 12345, …}
1: {OperatorId: 2, FirstName: "driver2", LastName: "driver2", LicenseNumber: 23456, RFIDNumber: 23456, …}
2: {OperatorId: 3, FirstName: "driver3", LastName: "driver3", LicenseNumber: 34567, RFIDNumber: 34567, …}
3: {OperatorId: 4, FirstName: "driver4", LastName: "driver4", LicenseNumber: 45678, RFIDNumber: 45678, …}
4: {OperatorId: 5, FirstName: "driver5", LastName: "driver5", LicenseNumber: 56789, RFIDNumber: 56789, …}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is  your `loadData()` async function returns before you get a response.

To fix that, change your `loadData` function to return a promise.

```
loadData: function(filter){
    return $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "/operator/GridJson",
        data:filter,
        dataType:"JSON",
    });
}
```

**[Edit]**

Actually, if you inspect the source with the  `F12` developer tool, you will find the fields rendered already. It turns out we also need **change the `height: "100%"`** as it will make those fields invisible.

Here's a complete list of a working sample:

```
$("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    height: "400px",
    inserting: true,
    editing: true,
    sorting: true,
    paging: true,
    autoload: true,

    pageSize: 10,
    pageButtonCount: 5,

    //deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete client?",

    controller: {
        loadData: function(filter){
            return $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url: "/book/index",
                data:filter,
                dataType:"JSON",
            });
        }                  
    },

    fields: [
        { name: "OperatorId", type: "number", width: 50 },
        { name: "FirstName", type: "text", width: 150 },
        { name: "LastName", type: "text", width: 150 },
        { name: "LicenseNumber", type: "number", width: 50, filtering: false },
        { name: "RFIDNumber", type: "number", width: 50, filtering: false },
        { name: "DateCreated", type: "date", width: 50, filtering: false },
        { name: "LastUpdated", type: "date", width: 50, filtering: false },
        { name: "CompanyId", type: "number", width: 50 }
        //    { type: "control" }
    ]
});
```

**A demo:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, I've made that revision but I still get the same console response and no data in my fields

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe I'm not returning the right type in my controller?

Comment: @sam80e I update my answer . Turns out that the `height:"100%"` make these fields invisible

Comment: Oh my goodness!! I never ever would have got that! Thank you so much @itimus

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue recently and took me a while to find someone else to point it out to me, too.  itminus has a good portion of the solution, but since you have Paging enabled, you need to return your data in a specific JSON object.

```
{ 
  data: [{your list here}],
  itemsCount: {int}
}
```

It's barely in the documentation, as it's inline and not very obvious. (Bolding mine.)

> loadData is a function returning an array of data or jQuery promise that will be resolved with an array of data (when pageLoading is true instead of object the structure **{ data: [items], itemsCount: [total items count] }** should be returned). Accepts filter parameter including current filter options and paging parameters when

http://js-grid.com/docs/#controller